# Mongodb: $geoNear vs $nearSphere on huge, non-sharded collection: performance?

Tags: mongodb, performance, mongodb-query, geospatial

I've got a data collection containing tens of millions of GeoJSON records, and an operation I'll be performing very frequently is selecting all the points of a certain type within a predefined region. The database is not sharded. The regions aren't circular, but they are entirely convex and for each one, I know the centroid and maximum radius. None of them have more than 8 vertices.

So: Assuming I'm perfectly happy retrieving everything within a region's enclosing circle instead of only strictly within its precise geometry, will it be more efficient for me to use a `$nearSphere` query on the centroid and radius (and then trim out the unneeded points client-side), or should I stick with a `$geoWithin` on the actual geometry? Even a small improvement would be quite relevant here given the frequency with which these queries will be executed.

Comment: i had similar doubts some time ago and finally decided to move searching stuff completely to ElasticSearch. ES perfectly supports geometric things and in the most cases does do it  blazing fast. Some numbers: now my mongo contains about 500 million entries and ES doing the search upon this data set - 4 edge polying searching using geo coord takes about 50ms

Comment: @AlexanderPaderin In this case ES isn't an option.

Comment: ah ok. so sounds like it's just a matter of performance measurement then.. i would suggest to generate a sufficient large data set and collect some numbers. Good luck

Comment: Was hoping someone would just know off the top of their head, hence the bounty :) If not, that's plan B.

Answer (score 0):

`$geoWithin` is considerably faster than `$nearSphere`.

Depending on your use case it may be performing better to get all objects within a geometry from the DB and then sort the result by distance outside of the DB.